# Sorting Technique ascending and desending

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below html code I am having a name and age, on click of name and age the list items should get sorted from ascending to descending or descending to ascending.

This should be achieved without using any plugins
Please help me out how to achieve this. I am really very needful.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;
  }
    #content{
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid red;
        height:auto;
    }
    #sorting_div{
        width:300px;
        border:1px solid black;
        height:30px;
    }
    #name{
        display:inline-block;
        width:200px;
    }
    #sorting_list{
        width:300px;
        border:1px solid green;
        height:100px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="sorting_div">
    <span id="name">Name</span>
    <span id="Age">Age</span>
</div>
    <div id="sorting_list">
        <ul>
            <li><label>Jenifer</label> <span>24</span></li>
            <li><label>Kate</label> <span>18</span></li>
            <li><label>David</label> <span>25</span></li>
            <li><label>Mark</label> <span>25</span></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @j08691: I tried using the TINY TABLE but they are asking for code to be write for the sorting I need help bro, M not that much good at jquery/javascript,.

Comment: " This should be achieved without using any plugin or any external libraries." do you mean you want to sort with jquery without including jquery itself? check this out, its really nice and easy: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Comment: Only jquery plugins should not be used....

Comment: @MaartenHartman: Only jquery plugins should not be used.

Comment: no offence, but why do you include jquery in your question title then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try the below sample code for normal text in li element

```
var mylist = $('#sorting_list ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
mylist.empty();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Comment: But the requirement is on click of name and age the below list data should be sorted.

Comment: It tried your code but its not working. Please help me out with demo. please brother

Comment: could your pls refer to below fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mvysZ/ it is not exact code but data is being sorted perfectly on refering to the code you can implement your comoplete code